# If the column vector $N$ is nonzero, what is the rank of $NN^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

### Problem

Let the matrix $N\neq 0$ be a column matrix (same thing as vector?). Determine $\text{rank}(A)$ where, $A=NN^T$.

---

Since the matrix $N$ is of type $n\times 1$ ($n$ rows and one column) its rank should be $1$. The same should apply to $N^T$, thus $\text{rank}(N^T)=1$.

**Question 1:** Is it generally true that $\text{rank}(BC)=\text{rank}(B)\cdot\text{rank}(C)?$ If this is true, then it follows that

$$\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(NN^T)=\text{rank}(N)\cdot\text{rank}(N^T)=1\cdot1 =1.$$

---

**Question 2:** We can write

$$
        A=NN^T=\begin{pmatrix}
        k_1  \\
        k_2  \\
        \vdots  \\
        k_n
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        k_1  \ \ k_2  \ \ \cdots  \ \ k_n
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        k_1^2 & k_1k_2 & \cdots & k_1k_n \\
        k_2k_1 & k_2^2 & \cdots & k_2k_n \\
        \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
        k_nk_1 & k_nk_2 & \cdots & k_n^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

How can I now compute the rank of $A$ from this perspective and see that it's actually equal to $1$?

Comment: The answer to your first question is obviously no in general. When you multiply two square matrices of size $n$ and full rank, the rank can't be $n^2$.

Comment: But then that solution does not hold. What is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: In your last matrix, note that every column is a scalar multiple of the first column, indeed, a scalar multiple of $N$.

Comment: It may help to note that $NN^T$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the line spanned by $N$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - How is it a scalar multiple of N? I don't see that.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - How do you deduce this?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: that matrix is actually $N(N^TN)^{-1}N^T$, but it differs from $NN^T$ only by a scalar multiple (the middle factor).

Comment: Just look at it, Parseval. The first column is just $k_1$ times $N$. The second column is just $k_2$ times $N$. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a column vector of size $n$.

Then note that $N^Tx$ is a scalar (indeed it is the dot product of $N$ with $x$). So $NN^Tx=\mathbf{0}$ if and only if $N=\mathbf{0}$ or $N^Tx=0$. The former possibility is excluded by hypothesis. The solution to the latter equation is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, so the kernel of $NN^T$ is $n-1$ dimensional; by the rank-nullity theorem, the rank is $1$.

Comment: This is amazing! But how can you so quickly see that the solution is the $n-1$ dimensional subspace?

Comment: The statement $N^Tx=0$ leaves $n-1$ variables free.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow there. Why would the equation leave $n-1$ variables free? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: ??? $N^Tx=0$ says $a_1x_1+\cdots a_nx_n=0$, where the $a_i$ are the components of $N$. This is one equation in $n$ variables $x_i$, so there are $n-1$ free variables.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that too. So to sum it up just to check my understanding: You first take an arbitrary vector $x$ of $n$ dimensions (this dimension is ofcourse equal to the dimension of the matrix vector $N$) and then note that if $NN^Tx=\mathbf{0}$ then $\Longrightarrow N^Tx0$ and thus $$\text{kern}(NN^T)=\text{kern(A)}=n-1\Rightarrow \text{rank}(A)=n-(n-1)=n-n+1=1,$$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @Parseval: the statement "$\text{kern}(A)=n-1$" is not correct; the kernel is a subspace, but the nullity (the *dimension* of the kernel) is an integer.

Comment: So I should have written $\text{dim}(\text{kern}(A))=n-1$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are various ways to define the rank of a matrix, (of course they agree), for clarity we define it to be the dimension of the column space, i.e. the number of linearly independent columns.

For you first quest, let $B = [b_1, \dots, b_n]$ where $b_j$ are the columns of $A$. Then the columns of $BC$ are linear combinations of columns of $B$. For example the first column of $[BC]_{\cdot, 1}$ is
\begin{align*}
[BC]_{\cdot, 1} &= [b_1, \dots, b_n] \begin{pmatrix}
c_{11} \\
c_{21} \\
\vdots \\
c_{n1}
\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j1} b_j.
\end{align*}
Then it is clear $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A)$. If neither of the matrices are zero matrix, the rank will be at least $1$. So $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A) \cdot \text{rank}(B)$. Actually this holds in general, since if we have $0$ matrix, then both sides are $0$.

For your second question, $N = (n_1, \dots, n_n)^T$ is a column vector.
\begin{align*}
NN^T = N \begin{pmatrix} n_1, \dots, n_n \end{pmatrix} = (n_1 N, \dots, n_n N).
\end{align*}
It should be clear the product is rank $1$.

Comment: No, $N=(n_1,...,n_n)$ is a column vector and $N^T$ is then a row vector. So shouldnt it read $NN^T = (n_1,...,n_n)\cdot N^T=...$? How is it clear that the product rank is 1?

Comment: Think of $N$ as the column and $n_j$ are the entries of $N$. Read my last formula as operation on the whole column $N$. Each $n_j N$ is a column of the product, stacking together.

Comment: Yes, you're right I understand that, but I still can't "easily see" that the rank of RHS is equal to 1. To see the rank, I'm used to reduce $(n_1N)$ to it's equivalent echelon form matrix and just count the pivot columns, which s the rank. One more remark, the dot product of two vectors is a scalar, so $$(a,b,c)\cdot (d,e,f) = ad+be+cf$$. So why doesn't your RHS read $$NN^T=n_1^2 + n_2^2+...+n_n^2$$. According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html, the rank of a scalar is equal to 0.

Comment: @Parseval: I should not use dot. It was a typo. It is supposed to be matrix multiplication. Now think $N$ as a column vector, the row vector $(n_1, \dots, n_n)$ acts on the column vector.